# Is there a way to preserve the 'uninstall.exe' (prevent deletion of the file manually) from the install directory using NSIS

Tags: nsis

When the user deletes Uninstall.exe file manually from the Program Files folder. And then from Programs and Features if the user is trying to uninstall, application will be de-listed from the Programs and Features. But the Installed folder with files and registry entries still exists.

So, Is there any option to make the file (uninstall.exe) hidden or set permissions which prevent deletion of this file manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can make it a hidden file and you could in theory set the ACL to deny delete (the uninstaller itself would have to edit the ACL again before it can delete it) but nothing is going to stop an administrator from deleting a file if they really want to.

```
Section
SetOutPath "$InstDir"
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\un.exe"
SetFileAttributes "$InstDir\un.exe" HIDDEN
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
Delete "$InstDir\un.exe"
RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. In that case can we popup a message box while uninstalling from Programs and Features?

Comment: You mean, in case where the uninstaller is missing?

Comment: Yes, If the uninstaller.exe is missing (or is deleted from the program files folder) and when we are trying to uninstall the application from Programs and Features, can we popup a message box?

Comment: The only way to do that would be for the uninstall entry to point to your main application: "myapp.exe /uninstall" and the app would detect if the uninstaller is missing.